# How to Wait for Asynchronous Function Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that gathers step data, but I need a way to make it wait for its query to finish before it loops. I realize there are other questions about this problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it. The function is below:

```
func stepsAllTime(completion: (Double, NSError?) -> () ) {
    var stopStart = true
    while stopStart {

        x += -1
        // The type of data we are requesting
        let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
        var daysAgo = x
        var daysSince = x + 1
        var daysSinceNow = -1 * daysAgo
        checker = allTimeSteps.count

        // Our search predicate which will fetch data from now until a day ago
        let samplePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: daysAgo, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), endDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: daysSince, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), options: .None)

        // The actual HealthKit Query which will fetch all of the steps and sub them up for us.
        let stepQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: samplePredicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil) { query, results, error in
            var steps: Double = 0


            if results?.count > 0 {
                for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample] {
                    steps += result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
                }
            }

            completion(steps, error)
            self.allTimeStepsSum += steps
            self.allTimeSteps.append(steps)
            println("New Sum:")
            println(self.allTimeStepsSum)
            println("Days Since Today:")
            println(daysSinceNow)
            if !(self.allTimeStepsTotal > self.allTimeStepsSum) {
                stopStart = false
            }
        }
        if allTimeStepsTotal > allTimeStepsSum {

            self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(stepQuery)

        }

    }

}
```

How can this be done? Is there some sort of "On Complete" function in Swift?

Comment: Just to be clear... you want your `stepQuery` completion closure to be called before your next `while stopStart` pass executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that my comment was accurate.
You'd probably want to take a look at a recursive pattern, something like this:

```
import HealthKit

class Person {

    var nbSteps: Double = 0

    func fetchInfo() -> Void {
        let sampleType = HKSampleType()
        let samplePredicate: NSPredicate? = nil // Your predicate
        let stepQuery = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: sampleType,
            predicate: samplePredicate,
            limit: 0,
            sortDescriptors: nil) { (sampleQuery, object, error) -> Void in
                self.nbSteps += 1 // or the value you're looking to add

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in // Dispatch in order to keep things clean
                    self.fetchInfo()
                })
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the program to wait till the query finishes by implementing callbacks.

You can read more about it in the following blog post
http://www.charles-socrates-chandler.com/blog/2015/2/10/callbacks-in-swift

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, I already have this in my function, and it hasn't helped.